# How do I fix the error "couldn't load codegen backend" on macOS?

Tags: rust

main.rs:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
}
```

```
$ rustc main.rs:
error: couldn't load codegen backend "/usr/local/lib/rustlib/i686-apple-darwin/codegen-backends/librustc_codegen_llvm-llvm.dylib": "dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, CFURLConnectionCreateWithProperties): symbol not found"
```

I'm using macOS 10.11.6 with Rust 1.30.1 installed via rustup. gcc is `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)`.

Comment: I will blindly suggest to try updating xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem on a Gentoo system on x86. For some reason, the codegen libs have been installed to

```
/usr/lib/rust-1.34.2/rust-1.34.2/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/codegen-backends
```

Note the repeated `rust-1.34.2` directory.

My solution was to symlink the dir from the expected place; you must do this with `root` privileges:

```
# cd /usr/lib/rust-1.34.2/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/
# ln -s ../../rust-1.34.2/rustlib/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/codegen-backends .
```

You may have to repeat that when a new version of Rust is installed.